# Return nested/related models with manyToMany relationship through model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a ManyToMany relationship between `Recipe` and `Product`. If I request Recipes, I am able to query also the relating products, but when I request Product, there is no related model data.

I think this is because the relationship is defined on the Recipe model. How can I query the Recipes related to Product (with the `through` model info!)? Basically what I want is to query a product and see all recipes that need this product.

models.py

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    ...
    products_input = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='RecipeInput', related_name='products_input')
    ...


class Product(models.Model):
    ...

class RecipeInput(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

serializers.py

```
class RecipeInputSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    product_key = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.key')
    product_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.name')

    class Meta:
        model = RecipeInput
        fields = ("product_name", 'amount', 'product_key', )

class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products_in = RecipeInputSerializer(source='recipeinput_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 3

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 3
```

Comment: So you want all `recipe`s that you can make where the given `Product` is (one of) the ingredient(s)?

Comment: exactly, thanks, Ill add this one to the question

Comment: You should be able to access it using `product.recipe_set`

Comment: I know, but the question is not how to access it, but how to return it in a ModelSerializer and a ModelViewSet.